# Creating Bewjeled with Java, how to check for appropriate moves from user?

Tags: java

We have to make a simplified version of bejeweled as a project for Java. The user enters their proposed move, and if the symbols in an array are not a set of 3, the move cannot happen. How should I go about testing for this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So when you say "We" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way:
You can store the game board as a 2 dimensional array and when the user swaps two nodes, update the game board, then if there are 3 next to each other: kill those 3 and let the ones above fall (keep this game board), if there aren't 3 next to each other: revert to the old game board.

There are more complex ways to do it obviously, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

How about an infinite loop that runs in a thread as long as the game is being played that iterates through the array and checks for matches?